# How do I sort indexed data from a form and maintain list from a range input added afterwards?

Tags: google-forms, sorting

I want to sort the responses by names alphabetically Column A (Simple)

I want to apply payment types from a drop down linked to the person's name Column G (Simple)

I want to do both of these things with new form responses coming in (Impossible?!)

Please help.

[Sample Sheet with Responses](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17KzoWAgxt3NyyDpJqrPT9OKda8sBfMs0WV1Ce9v9GKM/edit#gid=181782838)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the formula in cell `A2` and use this [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) in cell `A1`:

`={ 'Form Responses 1'!C$1:E }`

Then create a [filter view](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to sort the sheet by column `A`. Filter views can be saved for re-use. You can open a filter view with a link in cell `H1` like this:

`=hyperlink("#gid=1483996664&fvid=1156058788", "Sort by A (Admin Notes)")`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17KzoWAgxt3NyyDpJqrPT9OKda8sBfMs0WV1Ce9v9GKM/edit#gid=1483996664&fvid=1156058788).

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Now if filter views only worked on mobile I would be set! I am not sure about Android but on iOS Sheets I cannot enable the filter view with the link :(

Comment: I do not know how to make filter views work on mobile. You will need a different solution. This question did not specify that detail, so please post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)